# view frame does not move down 20px (height of the statusbar)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

I used the code below to present vViewController1

```
  @property (retain,nonatomic) ViewController1 *vViewController1;
```

...

push vViewController1 from rootViewController

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vViewController1 animated:NO];
```

Viewcontroller1's viewWillAppear

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        if (self.navigationController) {
            CGRect frame = self.navigationController.view.frame;
            frame.origin.y = 20;
            frame.size.height = screen.size.height - 20;
            self.navigationController.view.frame = frame;

        } else {
            if ([self respondsToSelector: @selector(containerView)]) {
                UIView *containerView = (UIView *)[self performSelector: @selector(containerView)];

                CGRect frame = containerView.frame;
                frame.origin.y = 20;
                frame.size.height = screen.size.height - 20;
                containerView.frame = frame;
            } else {
                CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
               frame.origin.y = 20;
               frame.size.height = screen.size.height - 20;
                self.view.frame = frame;

            }
        }
    }  

}
```

but it displays as below and does not move down 20px(height of  the statusbar)

[image]

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are NOT using Autolayout (seeing as you are playing with frame sizes) then in Storyboard select the ViewController and then goto the Size Inspector (little ruler) and then adjust the Y delta for the view (change to 20 or -20 depending on what mode you are "View As").

This may help [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8940) although I am not sure about the 18 value in Y I always thought it was 20!

Comment: I donot use Storyboard, just view without autolayout, and my code worked in ios7 but failed in ios 8